# How to use keyboard events to change the image for a slide-show

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use mouse events in a slideshow in Javascript. How do I use the keyup event to change the image? If I use `KeyUp` in the text box it's working, but when I use it on the image below it doesn't work.

```
<script>
    var image=document.getElementById("x")
    image.addEventListener("keyup",displaykey,false)
    image.addEventListener("click",previous,false)
    image.addEventListener("contextmenu",next,false)

    var step=1;
    function previous()
    {
      step--;
      if(step==0)
      {
          step=3;
      }
      document.slide.src=eval("show"+step+".src")
    }
    function next(event)
    {
      step++;
      if(step==4)
      {
          step=1;
      }
      document.slide.src=eval("show"+step+".src")
      event.preventDefault()
    }

    function displaykey(event)
    {
        console.log(e.target)
        var unicode=e.keyCode 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        if((unicode==33)||(unicode==38)) 
        {
            previous();
        }
        else if((unicode==40)||(unicode==34))
        {
             next();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: mouse events don't have keycodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard events for viewing the next and previous for a larger images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502503/keyboard-events-for-viewing-the-next-and-previous-for-a-larger-images)

Comment: @user2815407: Please do not use all upper-case letters in title, it looks like shouting. Also no need to mention *in Javascript* in the title because the question is already tagged to Javascript :) Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are wanting to change the image on a `keyup` event and only use javascript the following code will work :

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var image = document.getElementById('x');

    //Left Key
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        previous();
        //Right Key
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        next();
    }
}
```

This code will execute the `onclick` event of the image you have whenever the user lifts the left or right directional keys. You can change the keycodes and add more should you wish.

Comment: i USED MOUSE KEYS FOR CHANGING IMAGE BUT I WANT TO USE KEYBOARD KEYS TO CHANGE THE IMAGE

Comment: Hey, don't use all caps while commenting as it seems you are shouting

Comment: @user2815407 I have edited my Answer to supply sample code and a brief explanation of what it is doing.

Comment: Nunners but right key is not working because the step variable  in that function does not changing

Comment: Apologies, I have now changed the example again to now execute your `previous()` and `next()` functions. Let me know if you still have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use JQuery [hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin that

> lets you easily add and remove handlers for keyboard events anywhere in your code supporting almost any key combination.

Comment: I want to use only javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
function displaykey(event) {
    console.log(e.target)
    var unicode=e.keyCode 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    if((unicode==33)||(unicode==38)) {
        previous();
    } else if((unicode==40)||(unicode==34)) {
        next();
    }
}
```

I think the error occurs here as you passed `event` in argument and is then using `e` instead of `event`.